# Which of following inequalities hold in interval 0 to pi/2

Tags: calculus, arithmetic

[image]

i tried using calculator and i got 1,2,4 correct .But i am not sure about how to prove them

Comment: B is not correct. tan(x) blows up at $pi/2$, so it can't be less than x near $pi/2$. Which book is this from by the way?

Comment: $\cos x$ is decreasing on $(0,\pi/2)$, and $\sin x < x$

Answer (score 1):

For C,
I recognize the right side
as the first 3 terms
of the binomial theorem expansion
of
$\sqrt{1+x}$.

If it is squared,
we get

$\begin{array}\\
(1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8})^2
&=1+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^4}{64}
+2\frac{x}{2}-2\frac{x^2}{8}-2\frac{x^3}{16}\\
&=1+x-\frac{x^3}{8}+\frac{x^4}{64}\\
&=1+x-\frac{x^3}{8}(1-\frac{x}{8})\\
&< 1+x\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Binomial theorem expansion? The exponent is not an integer. Don't you mean Taylor expansion?

Comment: Generalized binomial theorem: $(1+x)^a = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n} x^n$.

Answer (score 0):

D) is correct. Since the exponential function is monotone, it is equivalent to saying that the function $f(x) = 2 + x - e^{(1-x^2)/2}$ is positive on the interval $(0, \pi/2)$. We obviously have $f(0) > 0$ and 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = 1 + xe^{\frac{1-x^2}{2}} > 0 \text{ for }x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})
$$
which shows the desired inequality.